# How can I tell if I have a ground wire?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I was looking at my service panel and noticed I don’t see any wires leading to the ground. Is it possible there is no ground or maybe the ground comes from my service? I have four wires coming in. I suppose there are 2 hot, 1 neutral and so is the 4 one ground? This is an older home and I am looking to upgrade my circuit breaker and I want to ensure I have everything in place before I talk to an electrician. Thank You[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSC38.jpg)

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for your *grounding electrode system*, or your *equipment grounding system*?  Because it looks like you have a four-wire feed from your meter-main to your indoor disconnect (which is good!) but without more photos, we can't see beyond that...

Comment: Also, it appears you've created two accounts, you probably should [get them merged](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) so that you can contribute fully to this site

Comment: One more thing: where do the red and black wires extending out the right of the upper photo run to?

Comment: I really can't quite figure out what the pictures show, but if you have four wires coming from the meter then it is likely the grounding electrode is connected in the meter. This wasn't uncommon to do in the past, but now is considered unacceptable by most jurisdictions since the meter should only be removed by the utility, and you can't inspect the connections without removing the meter. ***If you do have four wire coming from the meter then the ground and neutral should be separate after the meter.

Comment: You have an unusual setup with a 200 amp disconnect feeding another 200 amp disconnect, I see a utility ground at the meter but no equipment ground (local driven rod, pipe or plate electrode connected with #6 or a ufer ground connected with #4 copper being the most common types) prior to the 99 code what you have would need the local ground. But having multiple small wires on that 200 amp breaker have never been ok or another code violation is multiple neutral white wires under 1 lug. The inside panel should feed or be replaced with a new panel having appropriately sized breakers for the wires

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am just trying to figure out if I need to run a new ground for my new circuit breaker. The black and red wire are the two hot wires running into the home. I was able to combine my two accounts, thank you!

Comment: @EdBeal I know the setup is weird. They had a 200 amp in the home to supply power to old heater boxes because they didn't want to run wire outside.(At least that's what I think) They then ran another sub panel off the first picture which was a 100amp circuit breaker for the home. So I am removing the subpanel inside the home to then add a new 200 amp circuit breaker. What are your thoughts? Will I need to add a ground to the outside meter or is that my neutral wire.

Comment: @Zach -- is there only one cable or conduit running out of the left side of the meter-main, or are there two cables/conduits/wires running out of said left side? Can you post a photo showing the left side of the meter-main for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel So there are two wires being pulled in from the left and it looks like a neutral wire as well. I'll see if I can get some photos when I go out there later!

Comment: @Zach -- also, who's your electric utility?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I believe it is Rocky Mountain Power!

Comment: @Zach where does that wiring going out the top of the meter-main go to? Can you post photos of what extends out of the meter-main's top?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Well if you are talking about the second picture to the left, that one goes to the power companies pole. The first picture is the line going into the house. When I go out to the house tomorrow ill take some photos. Do you want photos of the line from the pole?

Comment: @Zach -- stepping back and giving us an overall shot of the meter main would help I think

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel So I took a picture of the wires going into the service. Looks like I have threee wires. It looks like the Bare aluminum is neutral? Does that sound right. I still have to call them to open the box.

Comment: @Zach -- I want to know what's coming out the top of the *customer* side of the meter-main. The bare wire at your service head is indeed the neutral, but that's not what we're after here

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I created a diagram to hopefully help explain and understand whats going on. Please let me know if you want me to add to it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will soon upload a picture of the new breaker box I am installing inside the home. Thanks for your help!